# Tensorflow for Apple M1 doesn't work as expected. Always get a PIL error when trying to train my Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I bought a Mac mini with M1 chip yesterday, because my 2018 Mac mini always got extremely hot when training a NN and it took like forever.
Now I installed Tensorflow on this Mac one time native in a venv and one time emulated with Rosetta in a venv.
The rosetta version works just as expected (but slower than my old Mac mini 2018 with i5 ?) but I can't get the code in the native version to run correctly, because I always get the error that's down below.
I'm also not able to install Matplotlib, sklearn and many other packages natively.

Code (from deeplizard's course:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import itertools
import os
import shutil
import random
import glob
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

os.chdir('data/dogs-vs-cats')
if os.path.isdir('train/dog') is False:
    os.makedirs('train/dog')
    os.makedirs('train/cat')
    os.makedirs('valid/dog')
    os.makedirs('valid/cat')
    os.makedirs('test/dog')
    os.makedirs('test/cat')

    for i in random.sample(glob.glob('cat*'), 500):
        shutil.move(i, 'train/cat')
    for i in random.sample(glob.glob('dog*'), 500):
        shutil.move(i, 'train/dog')
    for i in random.sample(glob.glob('cat*'), 100):
        shutil.move(i, 'valid/cat')
    for i in random.sample(glob.glob('dog*'), 100):
        shutil.move(i, 'valid/dog')
    for i in random.sample(glob.glob('cat*'), 50):
        shutil.move(i, 'test/cat')
    for i in random.sample(glob.glob('dog*'), 50):
        shutil.move(i, 'test/dog')

os.chdir('../../')

train_path = 'data/dogs-vs-cats/train'
valid_path = 'data/dogs-vs-cats/valid'
test_path = 'data/dogs-vs-cats/test'

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10, shuffle=False)

assert train_batches.n == 1000
assert valid_batches.n == 200
assert test_batches.n == 100

imgs, labels = next(train_batches)
print(labels)



vgg16_model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
vgg16_model.summary()

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:   #loop through vgg16 and copy the layers to new model, except the last one!
    model.add(layer)

model.summary()

for layer in model.layers:  #iterate over all new layers in sequential model and set them to be not trainable
    layer.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=train_batches, validation_data=valid_batches, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

Terminal output:

```
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 200 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 100 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 56, in <module>
    imgs, labels = next(train_batches)
  File "/Users/florianraab/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 104, in __next__
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/florianraab/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 116, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "/Users/florianraab/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 227, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    img = load_img(filepaths[j],
  File "/Users/florianraab/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 111, in load_img
    raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

After trying to install pillow with

```
pip3 install pillow
```

I get the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Users/florianraab/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (8.0.1)
```

Can anybody please guide me to a solution of this problem?

Otherwise I think I will return the M1 and stay with my 2018 Mac mini, even though I'm always worried because of the constant 100°C when training

Comment: Time/Epoch: (MacMini2018: 90s), (MacMini2018vEnv: 110s), (MacMiniM1:135s)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've already figured out the answer, but if not, here are some tips that might help:

1. The optimized TensorFlow for the M1 is not too difficult to get set up, but still can be a bit rough around the edges. Maybe it's a good idea to return and re-obtain the M1 later unless you're willing to put up with a developer-preview-like environment in some of your deep learning adventure.
2. If you look at the actual utils.py file that is causing the lowest-level issue, you'll notice that the exception is thrown by a failure in one of the following imports:

   ```
   from PIL import ImageEnhance
   from PIL import Image as pil_image
   ```

   Make sure they work properly. If they don't, consider uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow. Make sure your Rosetta setting on your terminal is consistent. This part should work pretty ok with M1.
3. After this, you might get a SciPy error if your routine takes advantage of `affine_transform` functionality (i.e. for image augmentation). If this happens, tough luck; as of 12/20, SciPy is not compatible with M1 MacBooks yet since it requires Fortran compilation.

   In the short-term, you can temporarily change `apply_affine_transform` into an non-SciPy-checking identity function if you are confident that it will not have an impact on your model's learning process. Otherwise, you can try to remove `keras.Image.apply_affine_transform`'s reliance on SciPy, though I wouldn't recommend it (I couldn't do it with the amount of effort I was willing to put in).